# Camera trigger driver circuit using Arduino to 2N7000 N-channel MOSFET - off behavior with 47 kΩ resistive load

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, load

I'm making a circuit to trigger several machine-vision cameras. Simply splitting the digital output pin of a microcontroller, e.g. an Arduino, works fine for a small number (<5) of the newer cameras that I have that have opto-isolated inputs that need 5 V and ~3 mA per camera.

However, I have older cameras that are PLC/designed for >15 V at ~3 mA. The newer cameras are built to be backward compatible; that is, they can also take inputs up to 24 V.

Therefore, I would like to build an Arduino shield that uses the VIN (DC barrel jack) supply to drive the output, so that I could put a 20 V DC supply there (max. allowable for UNO) and drive >5 cameras irrespective of whether they are 5 V or 20 V.

I breadboarded the following circuit, and it works great for a 2 kΩ resistive dummy load and a 5 V or 12 V supply to the load and then the MOSFET.

The cameras have ~1-2 kΩ resistance internally as limiting resistance with their circuitry. For this load, my circuit goes nicely between VIN and ground or ~-100 mV.

I'm curious though, as I increase the resistance of the load, the voltage in what I believe to be the off state of the MOSFET drifts upwards from 0 V. At 5 kΩ it's 500 mV. At 47 kΩ it's way up at 6 to 7 V.

It also becomes less stable, more "wobbly". See pics below. The first pic is the voltage across the load for a 47 kΩ resistive load. The second is for 2 kΩ.

Do I need a diode/resistor/something to allow the bottom end of the load to float back up to VIN such that the voltage across the load is zero when the 2N7000 is off?

My understanding is that source drain impedance is extremely high when it is off. I don't see parameters that indicate a large enough leakage current to drop down to 5 or 6 V at the drain when it is off - at 47 kΩ this would mean a current of 127 μA.

Also, why would the leakage current vary with load resistance? Is the load resistance somehow in series with the gate to ground 10 kΩ resistance?

Why does the voltage across the load stop dropping to zero for higher resistance loads?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYxDu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltage across load with 47 kΩ resistive load]

[image: Voltage across load with 2 kΩ resistive load]

Attached are the schematics of the internal camera trigger circuits for the "old" and "new" cameras. Old=24V/plc, new=5V. Thank you!

Old camera trigger expecting 24V/PLC:

[image: camoldpic1]

[image: camoldpic2]

New cameras - this is a constant current voltage regulator. EG takes varied voltage between 5-24V, outputs roughly constant 3-5mA into optoisolator. Allows new cameras to work with 5V or old 24V triggers.

[image: camnew]

Comment: Where does the camera connect in your schematic?

Comment: Sorry yes - the camera(s) would be connected at R_LOAD. Also I should have said the oscilloscope is across R_LOAD as well. Ty

Comment: Question is a little confusing. What kind of inputs do the "old" and "new" cameras have? Sourcing? sinking? neither? .... details plz

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @PeteW - camera trigger circuits added to post above TY!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your 2N7000 setup. You cannot, however place the oscilloscope across Rload, and assume everything's fine. You don't tell us if your 12V source is isolated from mains earth. If it isn't isolated, then your probe's ground (which *is* connected to mains earth) is going to mess up the potentials everywhere. Check this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two types of *sinking inputs*. Since both tolerate up to 24V, you can put them in parallel.

Your setup had them activated by the high-side resistor, and de-activated with a low-side switch. You would then need the resistor beefy enough to supply the required current to all the camera inputs, and then eat all of that power when your output is low (which is most of the time??). I.e. when your 2N7000 is on, the high side resistor would drop the full 20V or 24V supply, and dissipate \$V^2/R\$.

The conventional way to activate *sinking inputs*, is with a *high side switch* or transistor. As shown in your diagram 3.9.3.2.

However, we still face the max power dissipation scenario, in the event of accidental short circuit of the output.

Below is a transistor circuit with that in mind (clickable link). Noted in comments that this is a somewhat older style of solution, and you can get a *high side switch* IC that would reduce part count, and replace the current-limit with an overtemperature-shutdown function.

[image: aaa]

All your camera inputs hook up to TRIG (i.e., +) and TRIG RETURN (i.e., -)

The minimal functionality comes from R1-R4 and Q1,Q2.

- When the 5V MCU pin is high, Q1 turns on, which pulls current thru R4, turning on Q2. R2 and R4 determine how fast Q1 and Q2 turn off.
- Note that this is non-inverting logic, whereas your example was inverting.
- Q1 is a small NPN, like BC547
- Q3 is a small PNP, like BC557
- Q2 might be another small PNP (eg BC557) or a medium PNP (eg in a TO-220 package), depending on how many camera inputs you're turning on at the same time, and whether you want to survive accidental short circuits. You have to work that out.

The rest are protective features. If you just want something that works as a one-off you could skip some or all of them

- Q3 and R5 enforces a current limit into Q2, to prevent Q2 burning out if the TRIG output is accidentally shorted to ground (TRIG RETURN).
- R5 determines how much current it takes to turn on Q3, and when Q3 is on, it turns off Q2. So you must figure out what R5 should really be, i.e. high enough to satisfy on all the camera input circuits at the same time. In the circuit shown, all the loads combined are represented by a 500 ohm resistor, but that's just a dummy number.
- R6 pulls the output down when it's inactive and there is no load. It's mainly for convenience, and to stop someone else getting confused when debugging the system. The sinking inputs in the cameras will already pull the output down when it's off.
- D1 prevents our 24V circuit accidentally receiving power from the TRIG input, in oddball situations when different system components are partially connected or miswired
- D2 stops overvoltages and ESD, something like a P4KE33 diode

(note, all suggestions are thru hole, to follow the question's 2N7000)

Comment: This is a nice solution that considers some real-world conditions not mentioned in the question. Maybe worth mentioning why you chose BJTs instead of a P-MOSFET (I assume it's because the current limit is much easier to implement with BJTs.)  I also wonder whether this is something available off the shelf prepackaged in a single IC.

Comment: @Theodore - yes, for both points. You could get an IC high side switch made for 24V systems with overtemperature and overvoltage protection, and that would be fewer parts. They tend not to be thru hole tho. Or rig up an LM317 and a single transistor.

Comment: Omg @PeteW thank you so much! I need to digest this! And falstad, wow. I spent ages simulating the current regulator circuit above in Simulink. And no pretty animations... To clarify a couple things: 1) SimonFitch the power supply is isolated - in the sense that it is a two prong switched wall brick with no third ground/earth pin; it's a basic 12V DC wall wart; and yes grounding places on the circuit w/ oscilloscope ground "blips things around" 2) PeteW so i thought the cameras would replace R_LOAD and with no resistor coming off the larger supply (12V or 24V) before the cameras... prob bad!

Comment: @Andrew Spence - Oh I see what you had in mind. The unclear detail is the "common IO ground" on the input circuits, 3.9.3.3.2 and  3.9.3.4.2 -- Are they isolated from the other GND in each camera's circuit? Is it true that there are no other inputs connected to anything on any of the cameras? If so you could treat the camera input circuit as a 2-terminal device and float it as you had originally. The issue with the current consumption is still there, since when the 2N7000 activates, it would dissipate heat= 20V * (current from all cameras).

Comment: Lol well "had in mind" is obviously pretty basic in comparison - "got lucky" might be more accurate. but actually yes i think the camera opto-isolation ensures the grounds in each are isolated and yes there is only one input driving all cameras and this is it - so the 2 terminal device would be ok. supposedly the 2n7000 can handle 800mW but 20V*5mA max * 10 cameras=1000mW! so we'd split the dig out and have 4x 2n7000 driving max 4 cams each or something. i'm taking your wonderful answer as a problem set to figure out those R values, to finally grok transistors hopefully

Comment:    ... And I misspoke a little just now - the 2N7000 wouldn't be dropping the full 20V unless you shorted one of the inputs.

Comment: Ok thinking it through, a couple q's: How does Q3 turn off Q2 if Q3's VEC is so bug it isnt less than Q2 VBEon ? I can see how to choosing R5: say we want 100mA limit, BC557 has Vbe on of -.7 volt, so choose R5=7 etc. But how does it change voltage or current to Q2 base enough to shut it down? Maybe I'm wrong about VCE on of Q3.

Comment: @Andrew Spence - so it's really a limiter not a full shutdown. Q3 will turn off Q2 not fully off, but off enough that there is an equilibrium. At that equilibrium, Q3 \$V_{CE}\$ is the sum of the R5 voltage drop and Q2 \$V_{BE}\$ , something around 1V or 1.5V